# Minecraft monster spawner/trap

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My monster spawner/trap wont work. It is about 25 blocks tall, made of cobblestone and it is really dark. I'm on normal mode and I've tried hard but none will spawn. Heres heaps of pics of my stuff.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I just cant get anything to spawn in it and it has a like mini cave in it and lots of holes for them to fall but they just won't spawn. I've had it for a while and not one monster will spawn in it.

Comment: Hi sapphire, unfortunately we can not help you with your monster trap with such little information. I would recommend starting with the [wiki article on the subject](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Monster_Spawner_Traps). If you are having a specific issue with your trap, feel free to post it here with more information and relevant screenshots (properly labelled of course).

Comment: resorath, hey well it will just not work i dont know why this is my first time asking a question  no monsters will spawn in it

Comment: Even if they were spawning up there, they would not walk over the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Sapphire, you should try making the room big enough to hold water then make a bucket, get water, than make a little stream leadind to the hole so if any monsters do spawn they'll get flushed off the edge.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the pictures provided. You should take pictures which give more of an overview of the *interior* space. That said, I see two possible problems:

- It's not very dark. The hole at the bottom near the edge lets a lot of sunlight in. To make it dark, you should keep the hole 15 blocks away from the nearest column of sunlight — for example, build a 32 × 32 room with a hole in the center.
- It's not very large at all. To get a notable amount of mobs spawning, you need an area comparable to the amount of unlit caves and ground in the area. Build a large chamber with multiple levels of floors.

Comment: Hey Kevin well thanks for the tips im expanding my monster spawner ill see how it goes